# How to make login status persistent in Angular 2/3/4/5

Tags: angular

I am currently using a token (aka session ID) in my Angular 5 application where I pass it to the back end in a request header like this;

```
const headersForJSON: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders (
  {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
);
```

which is used with each request.   If client has a token (i.e. the user is logged in) then I add another header like this;

```
this.headers = headersForJSON.set("Authorization", v.authtoken);
```

This works perfectly unless the user reloads the application or manually modifies the URL in the browser. Also if the user right-clicks a router link to open another window/tab into the application.

In these cases the Angular SPA environment is lost and the **authtoken** variable is undefined so there is nothing to send to the back end.

Is there a standard practice for fixing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard practice is to save token in localstorage and reuse it when needed.

When user login, save the token in localstorage and when user logout remove the token from localstorage.

**Code**

Save to localstorage after login:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', Your_token);
```

Setting header when requesting for data in server:

```
getHeader(){
  let token = localstorage.getItem('token')? localstorage.getItem('token') : null;
  return new HttpHeaders (
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'token': token
    }
  );
}
```

Remove token when user logout:

```
localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

Comment: It would be beneficial for those less experienced than you if you could provide links that show how to accomplish this (e.g. a great blog post, Angular library) or to provide some code that shows a high-level of what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer it helped me get to a solution.  For Angular 5 I ended up using npm package simple-ng5-storage which does a good job of storing and fetching objects to local/session storage.